# Рекурсивный алгоритм для поиска максимума с помощью рекурсивного алгоритма для поиска минимума

Tags: c, рекурсия

Задание (все, что дано):

Описать рекурсивную функцию для определения максимального элемента массива W[23] введя вспомогательную рекурсивную функцию, зависящую от k, находящую минимум среди k последних элементов массива.

Убей Бог, не могу ни условия понять ни идею сгенерировать.

Обращаюсь за помощью к вам...

Comment: Знак функции поменяйте...

Comment: Какой функции? Мне необходимо, чтобы рекурсивная функция поиска максимума использовала рекурсивную функцию поиска минимума среди последних k элементов, не могли бы вы идею подкинуть, как должны действовать эти функции?

Comment: У вас есть функция поиска минимума элементов. Ищите максимум как минимум среди элементов с обратным знаком. Например, для `1 3 5 7 2` максимум — `7`. Но среди `-1 -3 -5 -7 -2` на этом месте стоит минимум :) Так понятнее?